# foreach mysteriously hangs on first item of a ResourceSet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance

Occasionally our site slows down and the RAM usage goes up massively high. Then the app pool stops and I have to restart it. Then it's ok for a few days before the RAM suddenly spikes again and the app pool soon stops. The CPU isn't high.

Before the app pool stops I've noticed that one of our pages always hangs. The line it hangs on is a foreach on a ResourceSet :

```
var englishLocations = Lang.Countries.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(new CultureInfo("en-GB"),true,true);
foreach(DictionaryEntry entry2 in englishLocations) // THIS LINE HANGS
```

We have the same code deployed on a different box and this doesn't happen. The main differences between the two boxes are :

**Bad box**

- Window Server 2008 R2 Standard SP 1
- IIS 7.5.7600.16385
- .NET 4.5
- 24GB RAM

**Good box**

- Window Server 2008 Server SP 2
- IIS 7.0.6000.16386 SP 2
- .NET 4.0
- 24GB RAM

I've tried adding uploadReadAheadSize="0" to the web.config as described here :

http://rionscode.wordpress.com/2013/03/11/resolving-controller-blocking-within-net-4-5-and-asp-net-mvc/

Which didn't work.

Why would foreach hang? It's hanging on the very first item, actually on the foreach.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure about it? Because Resource file size will matter a lot. If the size of resource file is big then there is a possibility that filling the var with values of Resource file can be a real issue. Try giving the var a datatype

Comment: I'm sure, been debugging it for weeks. The resource file contains 250 entries. I have many more resource files to cover different elements of the site.

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with the fallback resources. Have you tried to call it without loading fallbacks, like ´GetResourceSet(new CultureInfo("en-GB"),true,FALSE);´ ?

Comment: I will try that, but the hang only happens when the w3wp RAM usage is high. The resources are fixed so shouldn't it always hang or do you think the RAM usage is linked to the fallback hang?

Comment: Can you try taking a memory dump and analyze it? Have you done that already?

Answer (score 9):

I know it is an old post, but nevertheless... There is the potential of a deadlock when iterating over a ResourceSet and at the same time retrieving some other object through from the same Resources.

The problem is that when using a ResourceSet the iterator takes out locks on the internal resource cache of the ResourceReader http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/resources/resourcereader.cs,1389 and then in the method AllocateStringNameForIndex takes out a lock on the reader itself: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/resources/resourcereader.cs,447

```
lock (_reader._resCache) {
     key = _reader.AllocateStringForNameIndex(_currentName, out _dataPosition); // locks the reader
```

Getting an object takes out the same locks int the opposite order:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/resources/runtimeresourceset.cs,300
and http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/resources/runtimeresourceset.cs,335

```
lock(Reader) {
    ....
    lock(_resCache) {
       _resCache[key] = resLocation;
    }
}
```

This can lead to a deadlock. We had this exact issue recently..

Comment: Got deadlock in exactly the same pair of methods few years ago. MS opened coreclr source code, so I made a fix - https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/75. It is already mereged. I hope it will be included in the next desktop CLR release.

Comment: Does anybody happen to know if the fix is included in a release yet? Release versions don't appear to be managed on the GitHub repo.

Comment: Looked up the sources at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/download.html. The issue was fixed in 4.6, anything older will get you the deadlock.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced very similar problem.

Every once in a while IIS would hang, and I would see number of requests just sitting there. They were all in state `ExecuteRequestHandler` and with `ManagedPipelineHandler` module name.

After investigating with process explorer, I could see that all of them were sitting at `mscorlib.dll!ResourceEnumerator.get_Entry`, additional stack trace suggested some NGen action and then `ntdll.dll!WaitForMultipleObjects`.

My working hypothesis is that when multiple threads start enumerating those resources, we can run into a deadlock (possibly on some native code file generation), and alll subsequent threads then just keep on piling up.

To resolve it, I just created a critical section around this code block, to ensure that it is executed sequentially - I haven't experienced the issue since.

```
private static readonly object ResourceLock = new object();

public static MvcHtmlString SerializeGlobalResources(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    lock (ResourceLock)
    {
        // Existing code goes here ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based upon another answer to give you some idea how about using a try catch model ?
Perhaps it hangs because that resource isnt available / locked /..permissions etc.

```
var englishLocations = Lang.Countries.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(new CultureInfo("en-GB"),true,true); 
foreach(DictionaryEntry entry2 in englishLocations) // THIS LINE HANGS



ResourceManager CultureResourceManager = new ResourceManager("My.Language.Assembly", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
ResourceSet resourceSet = CultureResourceManager.GetResourceSet("sv-SE", true, true);
try { resourceSet.GetString("my_language_resource");}
catch (exception ex) {  // from here log your error ex to wherever you like with some code }
```